# How to get the value range of X and Y from the region defined by Boole?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to solve a multiple integral:

$\iint_{D} x y \mathrm{~d} \sigma$

D: y <= x && y >= 1 && x <= 2

I have to find the value range of x and y before I can list the integral expression:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Integrate[x*y Boole[y <= x && y >= 1 && x <= 2], {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}]

{*9/8*}
```

My question is how to get the value range of x and y ({x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}) from the region defined by Boole[y <= x && y >= 1 && x <= 2] by use of MMA code quickly?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[ y < x && y >= 1 && x <= 2, {x, y}]
Integrate[x*y , Element[{x, y}, reg]]
(*9/8*)
```

Comment: Thank you! @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @lotus2019 - to visualize the region use `Region[reg, Axes -> True]`